# Is it correct to check cancancan abilities for each record in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, cancancan

From the DB point of view.
For example, I have 30 records on page (articles) and I want to check whether I can create "Like" or not. So, there will be 30 queries to the db to check this ability. What is the best practice to perform such ability check?

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <% if can? :create, Like.new(user: user, article: article) %>
      <%= link_to "Like!", like_path(article) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE: Add ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :create, Like do |like|
        !Like.exists?(user: user, article: like.article)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please, show your `ability.rb` file

Comment: I don't see where in the above snippet a database query would happen? Is there some other code that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abilities per se are not stored in the database. here's an [example](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, it doesn't touch the database, since you already have a user variable, all you needed to do was ask about an attribute.

In your example, I assume you already have an 'user' loaded, and of course, you have a lot of articles already fetched.

if you cancan ability is, for example:

```
  user ||= User.new  
  can :manage, Article do |a|
      a.user_id== user.id
    end
```

then no queries are made, since you already have all the information about an article.

However, if you have to load extra information, something like

```
  can :manage, Article do |i|
      user.friends_articles.exists?(i.id)
    end
```

then a query is made (you had to see if the article belonged to the user's friend's collection).

No matter the scenario, there is no escape from asking each article for permissions, unless of course, you load only the articles an user can 'like', then, there is no need for asking ;).

**EDIT:**

Let's examine your ability.rb

```
if user.admin?
  can :manage, :all
```

User.admin?, assuming admin? is just an attribute, then it is already loaded, and no additional queries are made.

However, [exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F) consults the database, it searches for a like association user and articles.

```
  can :create, Like do |like|
    !Like.exists?(user: user, article: like.article)
```

As I've said before, there's no way to avoid this, unless you do some manipulations in the @article collection.

An advanced idea I can think of is to load @articles_liked and @articles_no_like, in one database transaction, and then mixing them for display, this requires a bit of work.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I've added ability.rb.

Comment: Thank you, Gaston! I think the better way is to avoid such approach at all if possible.